# Allow user to post to friends wall as user (not as app)

Tags: facebook

Is there a way (perhaps through a rest api or graph api) to allow a user of my application to write on a friends wall without the usual 'on behalf of' or posted by my application?  I know many people will not authorize an application that can post on your behalf, but I'd still like my users to be able to easily write on friends walls (without leaving the game page). I'm fine with it not promoting my game in any way - it should look just like it would if done through Facebook's site. I know there is something like this for Google+ using their mobile restful interface. Is this possible for Facebook and if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

No, I don’t think there is a way of doing that. If a user uses an app to create content, then it will show that he used this app.

Comment: So it is not possible to post text message with image or just text message alone to facebook wall without using appliation ID? 
As per my understanding, http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php is used to share the link to wall without having an application ID. is there any same kind of http url, which can be used for posting text message with picture or just text message alone?